# Simple Mockito Unit Test failed

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, assertion

I'm trying to produce a first test with Mockito in a Spring Boot Application.

Here is the complete class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ObjectServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ObjectRepository objectRepository;

    @Mock
    private ObjectService objectService;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should find object by objNumero with its service")
    void shouldFindObjectByObjNumero() {

        Object object = new Object("00000271");

        doReturn(Optional.of(object)).when(objectRepository).findObjectByObjNumero("00000271");

        Optional<Object> returnedObject = objectService.findObjectByObjNumero("00000271");

        Assertions.assertTrue(returnedObject.isPresent(), "Object was found");
        Assertions.assertSame(returnedObject.get(), object, "The returned object wasn't the same as the mock");
    }
}
```

And here is the error message:

> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Object was not found ==>
> Expected :true Actual   :false

As you can see, the test is supposed to pass because I've created a new object and I use the same reference each time!

Comment: Didn't you mean to actually make `ObjectService` `@Autowired`?

Comment: In facs, you have given the solution indirectly, I've use @InjectMocks!

Comment: I guess (sorry, I misread `@Mock` for `@MockBean`). My point was: shouldn't `ObjectService` be the real thing, rather than a mock?

Comment: Absolutely, that's why @InjectMocks is the solution, because that creates an instance and then inject the mocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've the solution. I've made 2 mistakes with the service:

```
@Mock
private ObjectService objectService;
```

Here I need the ObjectServiceImpl and not the interface. Than, I've use @InjectMocks instead of @Mock. For the moment, I already don't know what is the difference but it works!

```
@InjectMocks
private ObjectServiceImpl objectServiceImpl;
```